# Get attribute values of multiple DOM elements in AngularJs custom directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I've created one `angularjs` directive which combines `angular-ui-grid` and `modal`. Here `modal` shows selected/un-selected columns of a grid. User can select/un-select columns as per choice.

```
<example-Grid transaction-type="Example" id="ExampleToday" storage-variable="ExampleToday" grid-Options="gridOptionsToday" a-Column-Definations="aColumnDefinationsToday" initialise-Function="fnGridDirectiveInitialised(oStartDate,oEndDate)" grid-Resize-Function="fnHandleGridResizeToday()" a-Default-Col-Ids="aDefaultColIDsToday" dataloaded-Function="fnGridDataLoaded(sGridId,sStatus)" o-Modal-Configuration="oModalConfigurationToday"></example-Grid>

<example-Grid transaction-type="Example" id="ExampleTomorrow" storage-variable="ExampleTomorrow" grid-Options="gridOptionsTomorrow" a-Column-Definations="aColumnDefinationsTomorrow" initialise-Function="fnGridDirectiveInitialised(oStartDate,oEndDate)" grid-Resize-Function="fnHandleGridResizeTomorrow()" a-Default-Col-Ids="aDefaultColIDsTomorrow" dataloaded-Function="fnGridDataLoaded(sGridId,sStatus)" o-Modal-Configuration="oModalConfigurationTomorrow"></example-Grid>
```

The directive works fine with grid and modal if column definition is same for both grids.

As shown in the example, here column definition is different for both grids. And so `modal` configuration is also different.

Here the issue is I am not able to open single `modal` with column definitions of bothe grids in one.

**How do I pass attribute values of `o-Modal-Configuration` of both grids at once in directive ? And how do I open `modal` with both grid column definitions inside it ?**

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question, maybe read it through and make it a bit clearer... ?

Comment: Ok so from my interpretation - If you want to pass two configuration objects into the directive you need to wrap them in an object, or pass an array of them or even pass in a function that returns either of the above. Anyway you can think of that allows you to pass the attribute a single reference.

Comment: As for opening the modal with the two grids in it you would have to show more of your code for us to see exactly what your issue is with that...